# Scraping web data into multiple HTML tables?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-scraping, html-table, cheerio

*more details in comments

I'm using cheerio.js to scrape data and display in 3 HTML tables. It functions correctly, except the 2nd and 3rd tables have these blank rows added before displaying the scraped data (1st table has 25 rows, 2nd table has 25 blank rows, then 25 rows of data. 3rd table has 50 blank rows, then 25 rows of data).

I believe this is due to scraping all the data through one request, rather than doing 1 scrape per table.

This is my first time scraping so I'm wondering if there's a way I can change my code to fix this, or if I have to have 1 scrape request per table (but this seems inefficient).

Let me know if you'd like to see my mongoose schema.

HTML table to display data (using ejs):

```html
<table>
          <tr>
              <th>Environment</th>
              <th>Store Name</th>
              <th>Code Version</th>
          </tr>
      <% stores.forEach(function(store){ %>

          <tr>
              <td> <%= store.environment.QA1 %> </td>
              <td> <%= store.store.QA1 %> </td>
              <td> <%= store.version.QA1 %> </td>
          </tr>
      <% }); %>
  </table>
```

cheerio.js to scrape info:

```js
router.get("/scrape", function(req, res){
    request("http://link-goes-here", function(error, response, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var QAStoreInfo = [];
        var QA1StoreInfo = [];
        
        $("body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table").addClass("row");
        $('.row > tbody > tr:contains("QA")').each(function(i, element){
            var QAResult = {
                "environment.QA" : $(this).children().next(),
                "store.QA" : $(this).children().next().next(),
                "version.QA" : $(this).children().next().next().next()
            };
            QAStoreInfo.push(QAResult);
             Store.count({}, function(err, test){
                if (test === 0) {
                    var QAEntry = new Store(QAResult);
    
                    QAEntry.save(function(err, doc){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
             });
        });

        /* QA1 */
        $('.row > tbody > tr:contains("QA1")').each(function(i, element){
            var QA1Result = {
                "environment.QA1" : $(this).children().next(),
                "store.QA1" : $(this).children().next().next(),
                "version.QA1" : $(this).children().next().next().next()
            };

            QA1StoreInfo.push(QA1Result);
             Store.count({}, function(err, test){
                if (test === 0) {
                    var QA1Entry = new Store(QA1Result);
   
                    QA1Entry.save(function(err, doc){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
             });
        });
```

mongoose schema:

```
var storeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  environment: {
    QA: String,
    QA1: String,
    QA2: String
  },
  store: {
    QA: String,
    QA1: String,
    QA2: String
  },
  version: {
    QA: String,
    QA1: String,
    QA2: String
  }
});
```

mongoDB collection after /scrape call:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83600"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Omega  QA " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2019.11_2019_11.2 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83601"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Crescent Centre " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2020.06_2020_06.6 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83602"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Cumberland " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2019.11_2019_11.2 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83603"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " East Denver " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2019.11_2019_11.2 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83604"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Brookwood " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2019.11_2019_11.2 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83605"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " WheatRidge  " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2019.11_2019_11.2 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83606"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Aurora Centerpoint  " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2020.06_2020_06.6 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83607"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Castle Rock  " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2020.06_2020_06.6 " }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0610fee9b4c35d74a83608"), "environment" : { "QA1" : " QA1 " }, "store" : { "QA1" : " Conyers  " }, "version" : { "QA1" : " _2020.06_2020_06.6 " }, "__v" : 0 }
```

screenshot: (how the 2nd table shows up)
[image]

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? correct me if i understood wrong but it looks like your server side code you posted basically saves new stores into your database? what are these tables you posted? are they on your app? where do they get the data from? how does your collections look like after a /scrape call?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yup! so I use cheerio to scrape data from a website (not included in code for privacy reasons), then I store that data into a database. then i am taking the information in the database and displaying them into html tables on my app. the screenshot is an example of what the HTML code generates. I also added my mongoose schema if you'd like to see that...let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I also added a portion of how the collection looks after the scrape call

Comment: It just looks like your saving empty objects into your database (or that they are there already).

Comment: Could you show the query? it seems a projection problem rather than a scrape issue since the data in Mongo seems right

Comment: You could check if the row's value isn't empty before you actually store it in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Store` collection contains scraped documents with the following schema:

```
{
    "environment" : { "QA":  <string> } ,  
    "store" : { "QA": <string> },
    "version" :  { "QA": <string> }
}
```

and

```
{
    "environment" : { "QA1":  <string> } ,  
    "store" : { "QA1": <string> },
    "version" :  { "QA1": <string> }
}
```

> The empty rows in the HTML table are for records with the first schema where `QA1` is `undefined` in `environment`, `store` and `version` fields of the document.

I propose harmonizing the schema for a `Store` document to the following one:

```
{
    "kind": "QA|QA1",
    "environment" : <string> ,  
    "store" : <string> ,
    "version" :  <string>
}
```

Then updating your scraper script to store documents as follows:

```
//...
            var QAResult = {
                "kind": "QA",
                "environment" : $(this).children().next(),
                "store" : $(this).children().next().next(),
                "version" : $(this).children().next().next().next()
            };
            QAStoreInfo.push(QAResult);
 
//...

            var QA1Result = {
                "kind": "QA1",
                "environment" : $(this).children().next(),
                "store" : $(this).children().next().next(),
                "version" : $(this).children().next().next().next()
            };

            QA1StoreInfo.push(QA1Result);
```

The `forEach` loop in the `ejs` template can be updated as follows:

```
     <% stores.forEach(function(store){ %>

          <tr>
              <td> <%= store.environment %> </td>
              <td> <%= store.store %> </td>
              <td> <%= store.version %> </td>
          </tr>
      <% }); %>
```

Comment: thanks for your help! just had some computer issues and now having trouble setting everything back up so I won't be able to test this for a while..but bounty is yours!

Comment: No worries. When you get back to test it and this answer resolves the issue could you mark this as the answer to your question?